# What should I use (Past perfect or Past Simple)

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple, past-continuous

I have the following sentences. And must choose on of the tences (Past Simple, Past Perfect, Past Continuos, Past Perfect Continuos):

1. Sally Deedes was walking home late one night. She (be) to a dinner party at her friends' house.
2. Her friend Mark (offer) to walk home with her, but as she (live) only a mile away, she (tell) him that she would be OK.
3. She (stop) and (turn) around, but she couldn't see anyone and the footsteps (stop) as well.
4. She (begin) to feel afraid.
5. He tried to explain that he (be) worried about her and (decide) to follow her home.

I put next options:

1. had been
2. offered, lived, told
3. stopped, turned, stopped
4. began
5. was, decided

But the answers from the keys differ from my:

1. had been
2. had offered, lived, had told
3. stopped, turned, had stopped / stopped
4. began / was beggining
5. had been, had decided

Which are correct (are my items possible)? Would you my explaining it to me?

Comment: Is this question too awkward?

Comment: I am not a native, so it's realy important for me to know the answer to this question

Comment: Your answers for 1-4 are fine. I agree with the answer key for 5.

Answer (score 0):

Sally Deedes 1)....(walk) home late one night. She 2)....(be) to dinner party at her 

friend’s house. The city streets 3)....(be) empty and 4).... (rain) slightly. She 

5)....(

look forward) to getting safely home to bed because at dinner her friends 

6)....(talk) about a dangerous murderer who 7)....(escape) from prison the week 

before. Her friend Mark 8)....(offer) to walk home with her but, as she 9)....(live) 

a mile away, she 10)....(te

ll) him that she would be ok. She was about halfway 

home when she 11)....(hear) footsteps behind her. She 12)....(stop) and 

13)....(turn) around, but she couldn’t see anyone and the footsteps 14)....(stop) as 

well. When she continued on her way the footsteps 15)....

(start) again. She 

16)....(begin) to feel again. She started to run. The footsteps 17)....(get) closer. 

Suddenly she 18)....(feel) a hand on her shoulder and she 19)....(scream) in terror. 

‘Sally! Sally! It’s me, Mark!’ He tried to explain that he 20)....(be) worrie

d about 

her and 21)....(decide) to follow her home. But Sally 22)....(can/not) hear a word because she 23) ..... (already/faint).